# JQuery-UI Datepicker() click Done programmitally

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Does anybody know how I can trigger the datepicker to fire its **onClose()** function as if the user made the selection and clicked the **Done** button?

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place but I cannot seem to find a way to fire an event that mimics the user selecting the datepicker and clicking on the **Done** button.

Here's my scenario:  I want the date to change when users select an option button.  If the user selects the option "YEAR" then **#StartDate** changes to Jan 2016 and **#EndDate** changes to Dec 2016.  If the user selects the option "MONTH" then **#StartDate** changes to Jan 2017 and **#EndDate** changes to Jan 2017.

There are **max** and **min** and **other requirements** handled in the **initModule** for both datepickers that only get executed when the user selects the datepickers, changes these dates, and clicks on the **Done** button.  I want to fire these events without the user having to manually change the dates.

In my initModule method:

```
    // ----------------Begin Public Methods----------------------------//
    var initModule = function () {
        var currYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        // Hookup datepickers
        $(#EndDate).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            minDate: new Date(2013, 9, 1),
            maxDate: '-1d',
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('calendar-off');
                }, 0);
            },

            onClose: function () {
                var month = $(#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $(#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

                $(this).datepicker('setDate' new Date(year, month, 1));
                onChangeEndDate();
            }
        });
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    };
    return { initModule: initModule };
```

So, I've tried `$("#EndDate").click('onClose');` and `$("#EndDate").trigger('onClose');` and I've poked around everywhere to find an answer to no avail.

How to I get execution into the **onClose: function ()** without the user having to manually change the date in the datepicker and select the **Done** button?

Comment: Wouldn't you just set the date input value to the value you want?  And fire the events you want?  The DatePicker is just a graphical tool to set the date input value.  You shouldn't need to interact with it.

Comment: I need to fire the the onClose function to set min and max values as required.  I've already tried to set the values as you suggested but the datepicker fights with me.  There must be a way to trigger the datepicker as if the user did it.  Isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-hide), the `hide()` method will close the datepicker.

So, if you want to close the datepicker, you should do

```
$(#EndDate).datepicker( "hide" );
```

Comment: Good try but execution never goes into the onClose() function, which only occurs when user changes the date.

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak - Yes it does work in your jsfiddle, but note that is because the user is selecting a date and closing the datepicker.  I want to mimic this programmatically "WITHOUT" user input from the datepicker.

Comment: @Patricia i dont think there are any users in that fiddle, the datepicker is opened and closed after 5s by javascript timeout

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak - It didn't work from within another section of my code.  But, you did make me think!  I added a `$(#EndDate).datepicker( "show" );` and then immediately a `$(#EndDate).datepicker( "hide" );` and it worked!   Thank you  :-)